# How to put a button in a header of ASP.NET gridview?

Tags: asp.net, button

All I want to do is to put an asp:button in the header of a gridview.
Let's say you have a grid view with 3 columns - id, name, family. So, instead of a header [id, name, family] i want it to be [id, name, asp:button] - so the button will have it's action of course.

Thanks,
Roman.

Answer (score 12):

The approach you'll need to take is to make that desired GridView column a template field.  When you use template fields you can stick any asp.net controls into each main section of the gridview control (header, item, footer, etc).  I haven't tested this but in principal it looks like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="yourDbColumnName" HeaderText="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="yourDbColumnName" HeaderText="name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFamily" CommandName="FamilyClicked" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litFamily" Text='<%# EVAL("YourDbColumnValue") %>'></asp:Literal>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

To "capture" your button's click event and do something with it you need to utilize the GridView's RowCommand event (here's a starting point - again untested):

```
    Protected Sub Gridview1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "FamilyClicked" Then
        ' they clicked by grid view header's asp:button control...
        Response.Write("TEST")
    End If
End Sub
```

The magic here is in the assignment of your button's CommandName property (in this case I set it to "FamilyClicked" but it can be anything you want).

Here is some more fundamentals on the Template Field technology the GridView uses - [link text](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-12-cs.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

these are in fact LinkButtons.
you can use css to give them the look and feel of a *real* button.

however, it would be hardly elegant, whereas the trend in design is in fact use links instead of buttons (look at any popular web app you love, inc. this one)

Comment: I guess I didn't make my self clear - I don't want it to have the same action as the LinkButtons already there - I want to put my button with a different action (like going to another page).

Thanks.

Comment: if you just want to insert <input type="button"> it is even simpler.
use jQuery (or any other js lib) to get it done in a single line of code.